# (CubeIDE) How can i use printf and scanf on CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I want to use scanf and printf on CubeIDE (v1.7.0). Can I configure properties of project to handle this issue?

Comment: It depends where you would like to print and read input from. Printf and scanf are there, they just don't have the code where to write or read from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just tell printf and scanf what to do and call it a day like in desktop C/C++, where you output and input stuff to/from the console. There is simply no console. It doesn't exist. What's commonly used for debugging output is UART. Sometimes a command for MCU to send something over debugging UART can be labeled "printf".

If you want it to work like Arduino's

```
Serial.print("message");
```

you'll have to write some code (of printf function), and for that you need (I assume you want UART by default) to write a UART driver.

Some short googling led me to [this article](https://shawnhymel.com/1873/how-to-use-printf-on-stm32/), which covers printf and does all that fancy driver handling. Quickly glanced through, seems easy enough to follow.

Scanf is not a thing. You'll have to implement UART receving driver just like you need to implement UART transmitting driver. Whatever you implement, you can call scanf. There is no ready solution. It's simply not needed the way it is on desktop.

As an advice: drop this idea of printf and scanf. What you actually need to do is to implement UART, which serves this exact purpose (and which you hookup to scanf/printf anyway if you want those). You should look into HAL UART. Should be easy to roll out and get it working without knowing much of its insides, and it's very little code for you to write. A bit of googling led me to tutorials such as [this](https://developpaper.com/the-use-of-uart-in-stm32-hal-library/).

Comment: Inspiring but actually I want to use console. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @qt_goodi too bad for you. Microcontrollers don't have a console. It doesn't exist.